# Find Arima equation using auto.arima, daily long-term data (msts), 3 seasonal regressors, and calculating K in fourier

Tags: arima

I am working with daily data (variables include: temperature, salinity, wind, etc...) from 2002-2013 (`msts`), and I want to identify the ARIMA equation describing the whole data set, while also considering covariates unique to each variable, then use the ARIMA equation to predict each variables' values 7 days into the future from specific starting points in the data set.  Thus, `tbats` is not appropriate for me.

First I need to define the "order" and "seasonal" values for my Arima equation using `auto.arima`. Additionally, I believe there is seasonality in the data that is weekly, monthly and yearly so I am defining multiple "seasonal periods" in `auto.arima`.  Starting with predicting the temperature variable values, I am using `xreg` in the `auto.arima` function to include specified covariates, and want to also include the `fourier`/`fourierf` function for the dummy variables of month and year as well as a method for determining K.

Ultimately, my R code should be written to consider long-term data (2002-2013), seasonality (3), dummy variables (Month and Year), and identify the K value for predictive purposes.

Although I have found a lot of great help online, I cannot get my more complex code to work.
http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/ (and other Hyndman posts for complex seasonality, forecasting, detecting seasonality, daily data, etc...) and
[Time Series Forecasting with Daily Data: ARIMA with regressor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58657/time-series-forecasting-with-daily-data-arima-with-regressor/58673#58673)

I am using these packages for various parts of the code development:

```
library(MASS)
library(mgcv)
library(lattice)
library(epicalc)
library(caTools)
library(forecast)
library(McSpatial)
```

My simple R CODE below works - although only has one seasonal period, and no fourier function or dummy variables included.

```
Season<- msts(PaulsData$Temperature, seasonal.periods=30)
auto.arima(Season,stepwise=TRUE,approximation=TRUE,xreg=Covariates)
# Temperature: ARIMA(4,1,0)(1,0,0)[30]
fit<-Arima(June2009EventA$Temperature,order=c(4,1,0),seasonal=c(1,0,0))
plot(forecast(fit, h=7)) # fit is not very dynamic
dev.off()
View(forecast(fit))
```

The complex code below has the equation components I think I need, but it does not work... The K part is where things keep getting hung up... `"Error in fourier(y, K = i) : unused argument (K = i)"`. This happens anytime I use `fourier`.

```
y<- msts(PaulsData$Temperature, seasonal.periods=c(7,30,365.25)) #Daily Temperature (w/NAs) 2002-2012
bestfit<-list(aicc=Inf) # Select K value
for(i in 1:25)
{
fit<- auto.arima(y, xreg=fourier(y, K=i), seasonal=FALSE) # need the K-value, error in fourier function - K unused arugument
 if(fit$aicc<bestfit$aicc)
   bestfit<-fit
 else break;
}
dummyMonth<- fourier(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=30),K=bestfit)   # need the K-value, error in fourier function - K unused argument
ZdummyMonth<- fourierf(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=30, h=7),K=bestfit)
dummyYear<- fourier(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=365.25),K=bestfit)
ZdummyYear<- fourierf(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=365.25, h=7),K=bestfit)
fit<- auto.arima(y,xreg=cbind(dummyMonth,dummyYear,Covariates),seasonal=FALSE)
plot(forecast(fit, h=7))
```

Even if I use the code below to exclude the selection of the K value, it does not work?!

```
y<- msts(PaulsData$Temperature, seasonal.periods=c(7,30,365.25)) #Daily Temperature (w/NAs) 2002-2012
dummyMonth<- fourier(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=30),K=5)   # need the K-value, error in fourier function - K unused argument
ZdummyMonth<- fourierf(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=30, h=7),K=5)
dummyYear<- fourier(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=365.25),K=5)
ZdummyYear<- fourierf(msts(PaulsData$Temperature,seasonal.periods=cbind(7,30,365.25), ts.frequency=365.25, h=7),K=5)
fit<- auto.arima(y,xreg=cbind(dummyMonth,dummyYear,Covariates),seasonal=FALSE)
plot(forecast(fit, h=7))
```

Where:
Temperature = a column of values in deg C with x-rows 
Month = matrix of zeros and ones with x-rows 
Year = matrix of zeros and ones with x-rows 
Covariates = columns of values in appropriate units (i.e. Salinity (ppt), Wind (m/s)) with x-rows

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Load `forecast` library and type `?fourier` to see the help page for this function. The last example there is for multivariate time series. It looks like you need to supply a vector K, not a scalar K. Maybe that is why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(forecast)
ts_ <- ts(PaulsData$Temperature, frequency = 1)
msts_ <- msts(ts_, c(7,30,365))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_, seasonal=F, xreg=fourier(msts_, K=c(3,5,10)))  # i,j,k
```

If this works, you may loop through `(i,j,k)` to find the "best" model. Make it sure `(i,j,k)` is no more than half of `(7,30,365)` correspondingly.

Comment: what it means > k=c(3,5,10) 
i am having daily temperature data for 25 years how can use this ?
because when ever i am forecasting it is showing me error

let say arima1 is fitted so when i used to forecast

arima1.forecast=forecast.Arima(arima1,h=306)

It shows me below error

Error in forecast.Arima(fit, h = 306) : No regressors provided